# RxBinding for MapView (Google Map)?

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-binding

are there any updated rx binding for MapView (Google Map)?
I found [this](https://github.com/sdoward/RxGoogleMaps) library, but its last commit is around 1 year ago and it's still using google play services map 9.6.0